# To dynamically change visibility of <b> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a data table to which I have added a custom toolbar and hidden the  of the toolbar.
I want to activate the  tag when certain conditions are met. The debugger shows that the code in the if() is run but the property is not changed.
This is my code

```js
// The custom toolbar element
let html = `<b>Filter by:</b> <select id='crs-selection'>
               <option value="1" class='client-specific'>Specific</option>
               <option value="2">All</option>
               </select><b id='crs-checker'>No Client logged CRs present</b>`;
$("div.toolbar").html(html);

var crx = document.getElementById("crs-selection").value;
if (incidentsArray.length <= 0 && crx != 2) {
  document.getElementById("crs-checker").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toolbar"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add more code to make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code in a delegated event handler

An array's length cannot be < 0

```js
const incidentsArray = [];

// The custom toolbar element
let html = `<b>Filter by:</b> <select id='crs-selection'>
               <option value="1" class='client-specific'>Specific</option>
               <option value="2">All</option>
               </select><b id='crs-checker'>No Client logged CRs present</b>`;
$("div.toolbar").html(html);

$("div.toolbar").on("change","#crs-selection", function() {
  const crx = $(this).val();
  $("#crs-checker").toggle(incidentsArray.length === 0 && crx != 2)
}).change(); // on load
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toolbar"></div>
```

Comment: @Chirag What do you mean "styling property" ?